# One line of my website html text is overlapping in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS problem where instead of wrapping the line the text overlaps instead, writing over itself in mobile browsers [image: text is overlapping]

I have gone though stackoverflow and tried the normal suggestions to try to force the text to wrap.  These are individual words so they should break on their own but are not.  Here is what I have tried

1. I added css with about 6 commands to force it to wrap using a style sheet
2. I have tried putting the text into a div just for it and then adding the style to wrap
3. I tried putting it into an html table to try to force it to wrap
4. I have tried the wbr tag to try to get it to wrap
5. I was able to get it to nowrap but that isn't my goal since that forces the text off of the page

Here is the current code, mostly my trying in desperation to get it to wrap

```
<div style="word-break: break-all; word-wrap: break-word;display: block;overflow: hidden;">
<p style="color:#004a61;padding:5px;margin-bottom:5px;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px">
<i>Beautiful photos printed<wbr> on canvas, metal, tile and wood - take your pick!</i>
</div>
```

The website is [here](http://www.clickscanshare.com).  I have recently inherited it (it is hosted on weebly).  No where else on the site does it do this, so I am a bit flummoxed by this.

Comment: Try putting `<br />` after the word `and`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your containing `<div>` is inheriting a `line-height: 0;` from `div#741331162420463225-gallery.imageGallery`. Adding `line-height: 16px;` (or whatever amount you choose) to the `<p>` containing the text solves the issue.

Comment: No problem, @GeorgeScott. Good luck with your inherited site!

Answer (score 0):

you have a `margin-bottom: 5px;` on the `p` tag

change to

```
margin-bottom: 0px;
```